# Mock query string in Play request

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, mockito

I want to test a method that process value of query string. I use Mockito to mock objects. I tried to mock Request object and set its query string but it seems that there's no method to set query string.

My question is how to mock query string in Request?

Edit: I use Java 8 and Play 2.3

Answer (score 1):

Use the `copy(...)` method of `Request` to add your own query string parameters.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Request

Comment: I use Java 8 and Play 2.3, I can't find copy method.

Answer (score 0):

There's `FakeRequest` for that, it allows to pass the full path or an already parsed body using `withFormUrlEncodedBody`.

Check out the [API documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/java/play/test/FakeRequest.html) for more info.